# How to Access variable from another class in same package in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, bufferedreader

I want to access the class `Totalnoofwords` in class newrepeatedcount.
I want to print "a" of class `Totalnoofwords` megring with

```
System.out.println("( "+file1.getName() +" )-" +"Total words counted:"+total);
```

in class newrepeatedcount.

So I could run both the code for getting `System.out.println("( "+file1.getName() +" )-" +" Total no of words=" + a +"Total repeated words counted:"+total);`

Here is the snippet of 1 output which I wanted
 ( filenameBlog 39.txt )-Total no of words=83,total repeated words counted:4

Any suggestions Welcomed.
I am a beginner to java.
Here is my two class codes below.:)

Totalnoofwords.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

  public class Totalnoofwords
  {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    };

    File folder = new File("E:\\testfolder");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file1 = listOfFiles[i];
        try {
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
                BufferedReader ins = null;
        try {
            ins = new BufferedReader (
                    new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(file1)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String line = "", str = "";
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        try {
                    while ((line = ins.readLine()) != null) {
    str += line + " ";
    b++;
    }
        } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String s = st.nextToken();
        a++;
        }
               System.out.println(" Total no of words=" + a );
    }
        }
      }
```

newrepeatedcount.java

```
package ramki;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
public class newrepeatedcount  {
public static void main(String[] args){

FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    };
    File folder = new File("E:\\testfolder\\");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file1 = listOfFiles[i];
        try {
                String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        BufferedReader ins = null;
        try {
                    ins = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    String st = null;
try {
    st = IOUtils.toString(ins);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 //split text to array of words
 String[] words=st.split("\\s");
//frequency array
 int[] fr=new int[words.length];
//init frequency array
 for(int i1=0;i1<fr.length;i1++)
   fr[i1]=-1;
 //count words frequency
 for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
   for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
     if(words[i1].equals(words[j]))
       {
         fr[i1]++;

            }
        }
 }      
 //clean duplicates
   for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
     for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
       if(words[i1].equals(words[j]))
       {
         if(i1!=j) words[i1]="";
       }
 }
 }   
//show the output
int total=0;
//System.out.println("Duplicate words:");
for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
if(words[i1]!=""){
//System.out.println(words[i1]+"="+fr[i1]);
total+=fr[i1];
}
}
//System.out.println("Total words counted: "+total);    
//System.out.println("Total no of repeated words : "+total+" ");
System.out.println("( "+file1.getName() +" )-" +"Total repeated words counted:"+total);
}  

}}
```

I tried to put both the code into a single class 
but neither one of the variable is working
`System.out.println("( "+file1.getName() +" )-" +" Total no of words=" + a +"Total repeated words counted:"+total);`

When I run neither "a" or "total" is working.(vice versa) If i change the code (variable)order.

Anyone tell how should I get both the variable output??
:)

Here is my updated code.below.

```
 package ramki;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FilenameFilter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
 import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
 public class newrepeatedcount  {
 public static void main(String[] args){
 FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    };
    File folder = new File("E:\\testfolder\\");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file1 = listOfFiles[i];
        try {
                String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        BufferedReader ins = null;
        try {
                    ins = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
      String line = "", str = "";
      String st = null;
        try {
    st = IOUtils.toString(ins);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   //split text to array of words
   String[] words=st.split("\\s");
   //frequency array
   int[] fr=new int[words.length];
  //init frequency array
  for(int i1=0;i1<fr.length;i1++)
   fr[i1]=-1;
  //count words frequency
  for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
   for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
     if(words[i1].equals(words[j]))
       {
         fr[i1]++;       
            }
        }
   }      
   //clean duplicates
    for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
     for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
       if(words[i1].equals(words[j]))
       {
         if(i1!=j) words[i1]="";
       }
    }
   }    
     int a = 0;
    try {
    while ((line = ins.readLine()) != null) {
    str += line + " ";
    }   
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(str);
while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
String s = st1.nextToken();
a++;
}
int total=0;
   for(int i1=0;i1<words.length;i1++){
if(words[i1]!=""){
//System.out.println(words[i1]+"="+fr[i1]);
total+=fr[i1];
} 
}
 System.out.println("( "+file1.getName() +" )-" +"Total repeated words counted:"+total+","+"total no of words:"+a);
// System.out.println("total no of words:"+a);
}
}}
```

Comment: Your code is having redundancy. Since both classes are reading the entire files in a directory with content, next split the content to words.

Comment: Or can I create a main class and call both class variables? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package Packagename;

public class newrepeatedcount {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Totalnoofwords B=new Totalnoofwords();
    B.somename();
    System.out.println("a:"+B.a);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables inside the main function cannot be accessed from other class.
So you can modify Totalnoofwords.java something like.

```
package Packagename;

public class Totalnoofwords
{

    static int a = 1;
        public void somename(){
            Totalnoofwords A=new Totalnoofwords();
            A.a+=5;
            System.out.println("a"+A.a);
        }

}
```

and your newrepeatedcount.java be like

```
package Packagename;

public class newrepeatedcount {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Totalnoofwords B=new Totalnoofwords();
        B.somename();
        System.out.println("a:"+B.a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why static variable?

Comment: The changed value of a will only be for that instance, when we create new instance in newrepeatedcunt.java a becomes 1. If we want to retain that value we will have to make it static else you will have to return a from the methos somename() and store it in a variable in the calling method. and print.

Comment: I mean, I understand static variables are shared being class instances, but I think a simple member variable with a getter and setter would have shown the same concept of accessing values across classes

Comment: Even the getter setter will give the value of a for that instance of the object. Unless the same variable is accessed by all the instances.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 main methods in the same package, I'm not sure if you wanted it this way or not, but this won't work because your not **overloading** the methods. For instance currently you have public static void main(String[] args) in one class, If you change the other class to accept an extra argument public static void main(String[] args1, String[]args2).

Also in order to access  your second class, as stated above you would use something like

```
Totalnoofwords totalNoofWords = new Totalnoofwords();
totalNoofWords.accessSomething();
```

But this won't work, because you don't have a **constructor**.